# Is there a way to grab the public ips attached to load balancer and vpn gateway in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

All, I want to do is to list the resources (load balancers & VPN Gateway) in GCP that has public ips attached using python sdk

Is there a method to get the list of public ips attached to a loadbalancer & VPN GATEWAY in GCP?

I went through forwardingRules list documentation( Method:forwardingRules.list), but how to know whether it has a public ip or not.

Comment: Refer to the [blog post](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/google-cloud-platform-http-load-balancers-explaine) to get the Public IP Addresses used by load balancers and have a look on [Cloud VPN overview](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#comparison_table).Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hello @usertj has your issue been resolved. Did the comment help?